# Error while installing Sentry on Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, sentry

I can't install Sentry as on the documentation said.

I've followed the instruction on https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/laravel/ but it doesn't work

When I execute the php artisan sentry:publish --dsn=https://[key].ingest.sentry.io/xxxx command, it always gives me this error

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: If `SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN` got added to your `.env` as the docs state should happen, you may have a stale config cached. Try running `php artisan config:cache` then re-run the `sentry:publish` command without the --dns option.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter it's still error after running ```php artisan config:cache```

Answer (score 0):

It could be already declared `SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN=` variable in .env

Or it could be network related problems: you cannot reach sentry host for various reasons.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30303700)